# Do I need to specify Grid.ColumnDefinitions for a simple two column grid in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this code:

```
<ViewCell x:Name="ss">
   <Grid VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Padding="20, 0">
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
         <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <local:LabelBodyRendererClass Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Text="Show Subcategory" />
      <Switch x:Name="ssSwitch" Grid.Column="1" Toggled="SsSwitch" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="End" />
   </Grid>
</ViewCell>
```

I found that it still works fine when I remove the column definitions:

```
<ViewCell x:Name="ss">
   <Grid VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Padding="20, 0">
      <local:LabelBodyRendererClass Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Text="Show Subcategory" />
      <Switch x:Name="ssSwitch" Grid.Column="1" Toggled="SsSwitch" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="End" />
   </Grid>
</ViewCell>
```

So for simple cases like this are they needed.  So far I have only been able to see in the iOS simulator.  I'm not sure about when it is deployed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, if you want more than one column or row you will need to define them. I can't find anything in the documentation that says otherwise. Even if Xamarin.Forms will generate columns (or rows) for you automatically, it will always have the default width or height setting which is Auto. If you want to have any control over how they layout, you will have to add the definitions and specify widths and heights yourself.

You can easily test it for yourself, like you said you have done. If you want to be sure, create some scenarios where you try to expand the columns or rows without defining them.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the ColumnDefinition only when you need specific value for each column. Else each column will share the row's width equally.